# CUDA 3D array allocation and copy

Tags: cuda

Is there any corresponding method for 3D array allocation and copy like **`cudaMallocPitch()`** and **`cudaMemcpy2D()`**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cudaMalloc3D()
cudaMalloc3DArray()
cudaMemcpy3D()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cudaMallocPitch()` to allocate a linear device memory for 3D data by defining `height` as `height * depth` and get coalesced access in your kernel as long as you are taking into account the returned pitch from `cudaMallocPitch()` and some index arithmetic.

Similarly you can use `cudaMalloc3D()` to allocate logical 1D, 2D, or 3D memory objects on the device and get a `pitchedDevPtr` to work with in your kernel.